# String Concat com Join SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Boa tarde,

Estou com um problema com em criar uma linha de comando no SQL SERVER 2014 onde ele junta informações de duas tabelas em uma linha só.

Eu tentei usar dessa forma

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  SUBSTRING ( ISNULL ( STUFF (
                                        ( SELECT convert(varchar(10), C.nomeRazaoSocial) + ','  AS codigo
                                          FROM PEDIDOSERVICO PS
                                          LEFT JOIN CLIENTE C ON (C.ID = PS.MECANICO_ID)                                  
                                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '' ),
                                      '' ), 1, 254 ) 
                                         FROM PEDIDOSERVICO PS
                                            LEFT JOIN CLIENTE CL ON CL.ID = PS.MECANICO_ID
```

porem ele está retornando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu queria que ele retornasse dessa forma:

TECNICO,TECNICO2

Tentei de varias formas e todas elas não deram certo.

Uma delas foi:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT((SELECT ',' + CLIENTE.nomeRazaoSocial AS [text()]
                             FROM CLIENTE T
                              FOR XML PATH ('')), 2, 1)
  FROM PEDIDOSERVICO 
  JOIN CLIENTE ON CLIENTE.ID = PEDIDOSERVICO.MECANICO_ID     
      WHERE PEDIDO = 54301
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra forma q tentei foi assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + CLIENTE.nomeRazaoSocial AS [text()]
                             FROM CLIENTE T
                              FOR XML PATH ('')), 2, 8000)
  FROM PEDIDOSERVICO 
  JOIN CLIENTE ON CLIENTE.ID = PEDIDOSERVICO.MECANICO_ID     
      WHERE PEDIDO = 54301
```

Que também retorna assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Para obter o resultado desejado, basta inserir um segundo `DISTINCT` dentro da consulta da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  SUBSTRING ( ISNULL ( STUFF (
                                        ( SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(10), C.nomeRazaoSocial) + ','  AS codigo
                                          FROM PEDIDOSERVICO PS
                                          LEFT JOIN CLIENTE C ON (C.ID = PS.MECANICO_ID)                                  
                                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '' ),
                                      '' ), 1, 254 ) 
                                         FROM PEDIDOSERVICO PS
                                            LEFT JOIN CLIENTE CL ON CL.ID = PS.MECANICO_ID
```